# How to get detailViewController's view size in UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

**iOS 8+ ,Objective-C**

I'm working on `UISplitViewController` and i'm implementing textFields on detailViewController. I have bottom View for extra two buttons, bottom view's height is 60px and width is depending on device rotation.

So, i want to know that how to get detailViewController's view's size when splitViewController's displayMode is `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible`.

**Any help will be appreciated**. 
**EDIT:**
i'm trying with following code in viewController,

```
#define TABBAR_HEIGHT 50.0f
#define NAVIGATION_HEIGHT 64.0f
#pragma mark- ScreenRotation
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    [self calculateFrameForFooterView];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (void)calculateFrameForFooterView{
    //Caculate frame for footerView
    [self addBarButton];
    if(self.view.frame.size.width != frameClose.size.width){

        frameClose = CGRectMake(0,footerView.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width,footerView.frame.size.height);
    }
    frameClose.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height- footerView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat y;
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        NSLog(@"\n\n**(Landscap)self.view.frame.size(%@)",NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size));
        frameClose.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height- (footerView.frame.size.height);
        y = self.view.frame.size.height-(KEYBOARD_HEIGHT+footerView.frame.size.height+TABBAR_HEIGHT+NAVIGATION_HEIGHT-20);
    }else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait){
        NSLog(@"\n\n**(Portrait)self.view.frame.size(%@)",NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size));
        frameClose.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height- (footerView.frame.size.height+TABBAR_HEIGHT+NAVIGATION_HEIGHT);
        y = self.view.frame.size.height-(KEYBOARD_HEIGHT+TABBAR_HEIGHT+NAVIGATION_HEIGHT+footerView.frame.size.height);
    }
    frameOpen  = CGRectMake(0,y,footerView.frame.size.width,footerView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: did you try self.view.frame.size on detailViewController

Comment: @satheesh, i tried with self.view.frame.size and self.view.bounds.size but not getting proper values..

Comment: so whats your output on getting the bounds??

Comment: @satheesh, please check my 'EDIT' , this might give a clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alright, i solve my issue in `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{}`.
when i rotate the device this method called twice.in second time,i receive exact size.
  so first of all,i remove `- (void)calculateFrameForFooterView` from `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{}` than i put `- (void)calculateFrameForFooterView` into `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{}`.
so, finally solved my issue by doing this. however,this solution is not perfect but this worked for me. so that i'm not accepting my own answer and waiting for good answer. 
**THANKS**